# Getting errors on logout of user php and pdo

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, pdo

I have a done a PHP Login ad Registration script with PDO and OOP, all works but not the log out part and can't seem to get the errors solved. Please help me with this I am not so much clued up on php and mysql as I am still learning..

The index page is the page where you log into the site to can access the entire website and if I logout of the site it needs to go back to the login page (index.php)

Errors i receive:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for USER::__construct(), called in
>   C:\wamp\www\hooked\session.php on line 6 and defined in
>   C:\wamp\www\hooked\class.user.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: DB_con in
>   C:\wamp\www\hooked\class.user.php on line 9
>
> Warning: Missing argument 1 for USER::__construct(), called in
>   C:\wamp\www\hooked\logout.php on line 4 and defined in
>   C:\wamp\www\hooked\class.user.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: DB_con in
>   C:\wamp\www\hooked\class.user.php on line 9
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at C:\wamp\www\hooked\class.user.php:7) in
>   C:\wamp\www\hooked\class.user.php on line 70
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   USER::doLogout() in C:\wamp\www\hooked\logout.php on line 12 ( ! )
>   Error: Call to undefined method USER::doLogout() in
>   C:\wamp\www\hooked\logout.php on line 12

logout.php

```
<?php
require_once('session.php');
require_once('class.user.php');
$user_logout = new USER();

if($user_logout->is_loggedin()!="")
{
    $user_logout->redirect('index.php');
}
if(isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout']=="true")
{
    $user_logout->doLogout();
    $user_logout->redirect('index.php');
}
?>
```

this is the index.php

```
    <?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
{
 $user->redirect('hooked_index.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
 $uname = $_POST['txt_uname_email'];
 $umail = $_POST['txt_uname_email'];
 $upass = $_POST['txt_password'];

 if($user->login($uname,$umail,$upass))
 {
  $user->redirect('hooked_index.php');
 }
 else
 {
  $error = "Wrong Details !";
 }
}
?>
```

class.user.php

```
    <?php

class USER
{
    private $db;

    function __construct($DB_con)
    {
      $this->db = $DB_con;
    }

    public function register($uname,$umail,$upass)
    {
       try
       {
           $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

           $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_email,user_pass)
                                                       VALUES(:uname, :umail, :upass)");

           $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
           $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
           $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);
           $stmt->execute();

           return $stmt;
       }
       catch(PDOException $e)
       {
           echo $e->getMessage();
       }
    }

    public function login($uname,$umail,$upass)
    {
       try
       {
          $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail LIMIT 1");
          $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
          $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
          {
             if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
             {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                return true;
             }
             else
             {
                return false;
             }
          }
       }
       catch(PDOException $e)
       {
           echo $e->getMessage();
       }
   }

   public function is_loggedin()
   {
      if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
      {
         return true;
      }
   }

   public function redirect($url)
   {
       header("Location: $url");
   }

   public function logout()
   {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
        return true;
   }
}
?>
```

session.php

```
<?php

    session_start();

    require_once 'class.user.php';
    $session = new USER();

    // if user session is not active(not loggedin) this page will help 'home.php and profile.php' to redirect to login page
    // put this file within secured pages that users (users can't access without login)

    if(!$session->is_loggedin())
    {
        // session no set redirects to login page
        $session->redirect('index.php');
    }
    ?>
```

this is the page it goes to when logged in hooked_index.php

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

if(!$user->is_loggedin())
{
 $user->redirect('hooked_index.php');
}
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id");
$stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));
$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

and this is only the logout "button" and the display of the user name:

```
<div class="nav navbar-right">
     <label><a href="logout.php?logout=true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i> logout</a></label>
     <br />
     Welcome : <?php print($userRow['user_name']); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: User class construct needs db connection parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass `$DBcon` variable in your User object,

You need to change **logout.php** code a bit like,

```
$user_logout = new USER($DBCon);
```

Because you have,

```
function __construct($DB_con)
{
    $this->db = $DB_con;
}
```

in your `class.user.php`

And also replace `hooked_index.php` code,

```
if(!$user->is_loggedin())
{
 $user->redirect('hooked_index.php');
}
```

with this,

```
if(!$user->is_loggedin())
{
 $user->redirect('index.php'); // or 'login.php'
}
```

In your `index.php`, change the code from

```
if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
```

to,

```
if($user->is_loggedin())
```

Comment: But if I change this : $session = new USER(); to this : $session = new USER($DB_con); then all the errors go away, but still not log out and redirects me to my index.php(login page), it just refreshed the hooked_index.php page

Comment: see this, if(!$user->is_loggedin())
{
 $user->redirect('hooked_index.php');
},      I think this means when user is not logged in you redirects your user to `hooked_index.php`

Comment: So the only redirect to hooked_index.php must be on the index.php(login page) and the logout.php must redirect to the index.php page? If i look at it... hahah dam i don't know. this is my first database driven website...

Comment: It's your website, You should have your login flow.

Comment: or do i have to include the session.php on hooked_index.php?

Comment: It's based on what is your main work with `hooked_index.php` .

Comment: All I want is the after people register and login and load there things on the site to log them out to the login page again...

Comment: hooked_index.php is the home page of the website

Comment: Then yea, add it to check if user is logged in, if not, redirect to login page.

Comment: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()  get this error when i include it so not working

Comment: When i log in with the account registered it shows the user name and that is's logged in, but just doesn't log out.

Comment: Error's because the page has `session_start()`, twice in single page.

Comment: What if i take out the session_start(); on the session.php and leave the session_start(); on the dbconfig?

Comment: I think `dbconfig` don't require `session_start()`, `session.php` file requires.

Comment: ok i took out the session_start(); of dbconfig and it took me to the login page. but now new problem, when i login it doesn't go to hooked_index.php...

Comment: because in `session.php` file you redirect user to `index.php` not `hooked_index.php`, on successful login

Comment: <?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
{
 $user->redirect('hooked_index.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
 $uname = $_POST['txt_uname_email'];
 $umail = $_POST['txt_uname_email'];
 $upass = $_POST['txt_password'];

 if($user->login($uname,$umail,$upass))
 {
  $user->redirect('hooked_index.php');
 }
 else
 {
  $error = "Wrong Details !";
 }
}
?>

Comment: sorry the login is the index.php

Comment: check the updated answer, and where is your `password_verify()` in `class.user.php`?

Comment: Thank you it works just one thing happening now is that when i login i get this error: Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\hooked\hooked_index.php on line 8

Comment: and username not showing up under the logout button

Comment: replace `_SESSION` with `$_SESSION`.

Comment: and also accept the answer and upvote, so that others with the same problem can be benefited in the future.

Comment: i just look and that session is already $_SESSION... still have same error

Comment: add `include_once 'session.php';` In your `hooked_index.php`

Comment: This page isn’t working

localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: i have cleared my cookies and everything and now it also doesn't logout anymore back to square one

Comment: in`hooked_index.php`? If Yes, then look for `hooked_index.php` replace code in my answer.

Comment: yes, i did all the changes on your updated answer at the top then i cleared my cookies and now its not logging out hahah

Comment: I just updated the replace code for `hooked_index.php` in my answer.

Comment: Ok i did some changes and it works so now i still have the problem with the _SESSION

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\hooked\hooked_index.php on line 8

Comment: don't know why because its like this in the hooked_index.php : $user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];

Comment: The error tells you that, either `$_SESSION['user_session']` is undefined or you didn't start session by `session_start()`, so add `include_once 'session.php';` In your `hooked_index.php`, if it don't already exists.